# Google Cardboard in Unity: How can I set the Head's rotation?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

Alright, I've tried everything but I'm creating a VR app using Google Cardboard in Unity3D and I'm trying to set the rotation of the head object. I am able to print the rotation of the Head object to the console by printing `head1.transform.localRotation`and getting the Head object using `public CardboardHead head1;` however unlike other objects, I am not able to CHANGE this rotation.

I realize that the CardboardHead script continuously overrides and sets the rotation of the Head object here:

```
if (trackRotation) {
      var rot = Cardboard.SDK.HeadPose.Orientation;
      if (target == null) {
        transform.localRotation = rot;

      } else {
        transform.rotation = target.rotation * rot;
      }
    }
```

And I have even tried to alter these values however I just want to alter the rotation of the head object temporarily so that the Head object "snaps" to a certain rotation after the round is over in my game (after that if they turn their head the Head object turns like normal)

I just want to make the player "look" somewhere (I want them to face a canvas) but when I try to alter the Head object's rotation like this:

```
head1.transform.rotation = new Quaternion(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
```

or

```
head1.transform.localRotation = new Quaternion(0.0f,90.0f,70.0f,80.0f);
```

Nothing happens. The Head object remains in the rotation it is initially set which seems to be (1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0). Why is this? How can I change the Head rotation so the user will be facing a Canvas/pointed in a set direction?

Answer (score 0):

```
  head1.transform.localRotation = new Quaternion(0.0f,90.0f,70.0f,80.0f);
```

I would doubt this is a valid quaternion, more likely a euler rotation:

```
  head1.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(90.0f,70.0f,80.0f);
```

Your best shot would be to also deactivate the Cardboard so that it does not try to override the rotation. You'd have a HeadController that activate the GoogleCardboard or the other script based on state. That would keep the GoogleCardboard clean as well.

Comment: I tried the Euler with no success.. how would I activate or deactivate the scripts? And given that I want to return to GoogleCardboard normal head tracking after the user is returned to this original position, would you recommend having the deactivation on a timer?